# Is there a difference between storing the Selenium functions into a variable and not storing it?

Tags: python, selenium

I've been playing around with Selenium and Python lately, and one thing that came up through using Selenium were the functions calls, such as .find_element_by_name. You can either store call into a variable or not.

I'm wondering... Are there any differences and benefits to storing the functions or using the functions, like so?

This...

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('Hello')
elem.click()
```

or...

```
driver.find_element_by_name('Hello').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no significant differences between the two methods. If you were storing a LOT of variables, you might start to see an increase in memory usage.

The way I approach this is to use a single line if I don't plan to reuse the element.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('id').send_keys('test')
```

If I need to reference the element more than once, I store it in a variable.

```
input = driver.find_element_by_id('id')
input.clear()
input.send_keys('test')
```

If you do use a variable, you have to start paying more attention to what you do to the page between uses. For example, if you grab a reference to an `INPUT`, refresh the page, and then try to click it you will get a Stale Element Reference Exception. So there may be times when you reference the same element twice but you don't store it because the page updates between uses.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the object before execute a function you gain:

1. **Traceability** - option to an easier debugging - you can add breakpoint before click to view object and verify it.
2. **Readability**  - you don't have a long sentence that is harder to understand later.
3. **Refactoring** - you can use the object for later operations which can prevent code duplications.

In this case, it also reduces the run time if you are going to use the same element multiple times in the same program.
eg.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('Textbox')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('text')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can always store the **return** data from the functions calls, such as **`find_element_by_name()`**.

As per the documentation **`find_element_by_name()`** is from [**selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=find_element_by_name#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) class which returns a [**WebElement**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html?highlight=click#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement). As a **`WebElement`** is returned so you can invoke any of the following functions associated with `WebElement` :

- clear()
- click()
- get_attribute(attribute_name)
- is_displayed()
- is_enabled()
- is_selected()
- send_keys(*value) etc

### Advantages :

Invoking the required method to the returned **`WebElement`** have certain advantages :

- It makes your code much more clear and redable.
- You need to write less no of line, hence less code.
- Your code becomes optiomized.
- Some Example :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_name('element_name').clear()
  driver.find_element_by_id('element_id').click() 
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("element_link_text").is_enabled()
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("element_css").get_attribute(attribute_name)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("element_xpath").send_keys(*value)
  ```